# Why are some public squads "locked?"

Tags: battlefield-3

When my friend and I try to join a squad together (on PC), I always have to join the squad first.  If he joins it first, the squad becomes "locked" and I can no longer join it.  This happens even though he is not the squad leader, and even though he has his squads set to "public."

Why is this happening, and how do we fix it?

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654347902705049/) thread tells me the bug is common. The soloution seems to be for the squad leader to leave the squad and rejoin. It will most likely be addressed in the next patch since this thread is from yesterday. I have no clue why it would only happen when he joins first though. That is very odd.

Comment: Spot on @Emerica . I presume by your replies in the BF3 Tagged - you play?

Comment: @Foxtrot I play on 360. I built my gaming PC a few months after BF3 came out. I often toy with the idea of picking it up for PC but the rerank process would be kinda lame.

Comment: I have seen it on console, but I play it for PC.  I've compared the two, and personally I think PC > Console.  I would recommend it for PC.

Comment: Yeah, I played 1942, Vietnam and BF2 all on PC. PC is defintley the superior platform, I just didn't have the money to be building a PC at time of release and I couldn't wait.

Comment: lol good point with the not ability to wait. BF2, BFBC1&2, BF2142, and now BF3 all on PC here.

Comment: This is not the same problem.  Whenever he joins a squad - whether he is the squad leader or not - it becomes locked for me, but not for others.  It happens on all servers.  Him leaving and rejoining the squad does not help.